# Passing json object as url parameter

Tags: php, json, url

```
<?php  
  $jsonData = array(
    "comments" => "Fresh food",
    "container" => false,
    "cookedTime" => 2,
    "description" => "biryani",
    "refridgeration" => true,
    "serves" => 2,
    "veg" => true
);

json_encode($jsonData);
header("Location:Post.php?json=$jsonData");
?>
```

This is my php page which contains json object. I am passing this json object into another page Post.php.

```
<?php
$jsonData = $_GET['json'];
json_decode($jsonData, TRUE);
echo var_dump($jsonData);
?>
```

when I did a dump the result is  C:\wamp\www\Hack\Post.php:16:string 'Array' (length=5).
It is printing "Array" instead of the json object. What do I do?

Comment: The URI length is limited. You should pass JSON data through POST

Comment: Remove True from json decode function

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov IMO the lenght estriction is about 2000 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do json_encode you must have a variable to store the result:

```
$jsonData = json_encode($jsonData)
```

Without this, your data is still just a php object

Comment: Partially correct.  Will fail on many things without `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 5):

As 1slock says you hace to encode the json but also add urlencode.

`header("Location: Post.php?json=" . urlencode( json_encode($jsonData)) );`

Comment: I would do base 64 encoding to have this work all over the place.

Comment: urlencode should be enought and should work for any type of data. THe proble is if the json is too big because the server and the browser can crop it depending on its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code sample, you're not passing along the json_encoded value, but the array itself. Replace your last line with this, and skip the penultimate line:

```
header("Location: Post.php?json=" . json_encode($jsonData));
```